# Git and management rebase of branches

Tags: git, rebase

I create a new branch (pj2/new-register-feature) from [dev-project2] branch and I created a pull request to [dev-project2] branch. (pull request 1).

And then let's continue action rebase [dev-project2] to [dev-project1] and push force [dev-project2] branch after rebase.

But when I review [pull request 1] as above it was occur a lot of commit on [pull request 1] after rebased [dev-project2] to [dev-project1] branch.

So, Could you help me explain it and how to update [pull request 1] to only see commit of [pj2/new-registry-feature] which create pull request

Comment: I resolved it. It's easy to resolve. Only rebase [pj2/new-registry-feature] to [dev-project2] branch. 

But could you guys help me explain it via image graph of branch for this issue.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I understood your question (please let me know if I missed something) :

You started from :

```
--A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H <- dev-project1
      \
       \-c--d--e--f--g <- dev-project2
                \
                 \-p--q--r <- pj2/new-register-feature
```

And created a pull request to merge `pj2/new-register-feature` into `dev-project2`.

Then you rebase `dev-project2` onto `dev-project1`.

With the rebase completed, the graph now looks like :

```
--A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H <- dev-project1
      \                 \
       \-c--d--e-[f]-[g] \-c'--d'--e'--f'--g' <- dev-project2
                \
                 \-p--q--r <- pj2/new-register-feature
```

What you observe in the merge request is :

- instead of seeing : `p--q--r` as the history for your branch (wrt `dev-project2`),
- you now see `c--d--e--p--q--r`

---

If you want to restore something closer to the initial graph, you would need to rebase `pj2/new-register-feature` on top of `e'` (that is : the rebased version of the original fork point between `pj2/new-register-feature` and `dev-project2`).

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain it with out image.

After you rebase project2 to project1, you change all the commits in project2 (at least their hash) as the rebase puts them after the commits in project1.
In this case, your project2 commits and new-register-feature commits are completely different and you see all those commits.

Read the https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing for some more data, they explain what happens when you rebase.